# How to set Visual Studio as the default post-mortem debugger?

Tags: visual-studio

Not too long ago, I had a problem which required me to [set WinDbg.exe as the default post-mortem debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186237/program-only-crashes-as-release-build-how-to-debug).  Now that I've fixed that and am back doing normal work, it would be really nice if I could set VS to be my default post-mortem debugger.  How does one go about doing this?

Also, how do I make VS attach to an already existing session?  That is, I've got my VS project open in one window, and a command line open where I'm launching my program from.  If the program crashes, how do I get VS to figure out to attach the debugger to the active line in the project that's already open?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from the [Microsoft support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121434):

1. Start Registry Editor and locate the following Registry subkey in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE subtree:
   `\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS NT\CURRENTVERSION\AEDEBUG`
2. Select the Debugger value.
3. On the Edit menu, click String.

- To use the Windows debugger, type `windbg -p %ld -e %ld`.
- To use Visual C++ 4.2 or earlier, type `msvc -p %ld -e %ld`.
  *To use Visual C++ 5.0 or later, type `msdev.exe -p %ld -e %ld`.
- To use Dr. Watson, type `drwtsn32.exe -p %ld -e %ld`. You can also make Dr. Watson the default debugger by running this command:`drwtsn32.exe -i`.

4. Choose OK and exit Registry Editor.

Comment: for using windbg I used: `"C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\windbg" -p %ld -e %ld`

Comment: That page is crap & dated. See the other answer.

Answer (score 27):

You can re-enable Visual Studio for Just-In-Time debugging from within Visual Studio:

Go to the **Tools | Options** | **Debugging | Just-In-Time** dialog.  Then make sure all **Native** and **Managed** (if you're debugging a .NET application) are checked.  Next time you get a crash, the Visual Studio Just-In-Time debugger will come up.

The Visual Studio Just-In-Time debugger let's you choose whether you want to open a new instance of Visual Studio or start debugging with a currently open solution.

Comment: In later versions of Windows you must turn off WER. For Windows 10 [see here](https://superuser.com/questions/950997/disable-error-reporting-in-windows-10-home).