# Restore Windows application crash Debug button

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to debug a .Net plugin of a Windows service (actually a SharePoint service).

I use to hook my plugin with this method:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

However, on my dev computer (Windows 2012 R2), I don't have the `Debug` button that allows me to choose a debugger.

I only have:

[image]

It miss the `debug` button.

How to restore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/643031/588868).

> Go to the Tools | Options | Debugging | Just-In-Time dialog. Then make sure all Native and Managed (if you're debugging a .NET application) are checked. Next time you get a crash, the Visual Studio Just-In-Time debugger will come up.

[image]

And this restores automatically the `Debug` button:

[image]