# Debug child executable of a process

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windbg

I have an executable on a Windows system, e.g. `test.exe` and it is started by a process `parent.exe`. When I debug it in Visual Studio, I use "attach to process" to debug the `test.exe`, but by the time I attach the debugger to process, the entry point function in `test.exe` has already been called.

Is there a way to set a breakpoint on the entry point function in this setup?

Comment: test.exe can only be started by parent.exe, it cannot start on its own.

Comment: Visual Studio is not good ad debugging child processes. WinDbg has `.childdbg 1` for that.

Comment: Try setting the debugger in [ImageFileExecutionOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28VS.71%29.aspx) to Visual Studio for test.exe

Comment: [Child Process Debugging Power Tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a1141bff-463f-465f-9b6d-d29b7b503d7a) might also help

Answer (score 1):

If you control the executable, add `__debugbreak` to main. This hardcodes a breakpoint which you'd usually set at runtime.

When this statement is executed, Windows will start the [Just In Time debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/643031/15416)

Answer (score 0):

Use WinDbg instead. File->Open Executable and check the box "Debug child processes also".