# XML Serialization Errors in Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS, but not in Windows 10 IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, iis, visual-studio-2012

this one has been troubling me for a while now and I'm at a loss as to solving it.

I'm developing an application using ASP MVC 5, and just recently I've started working on a production environment. The program builds and runs fine on my local machine from Visual Studio using IIS express.

I've set up an IIS server on my local machine (Windows 10) as well and published to that, which also works just fine.

The problem seems to come out when Windows Server enters the equation.

Using the exact same published code and the same IIS configuration steps, I can't get the site to work on WinServer IIS. There is some kind of issue it seems with XML deserialization. The error I get is as follows:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 999). ---> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot assign object of type EpagesSOAPClients.CustomerService4Ref.TLocalizedValue[] to an object of type EpagesSOAPClients.ProductService9Ref.TLocalizedValue[].
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read14_TGetInfo_Return()
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadReferencingElement(String name, String ns, Boolean elementCanBeType, String& fixupReference)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadArray(String typeName, String typeNs)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadReferencingElement(String name, String ns, Boolean elementCanBeType, String& fixupReference)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read100_getInfoResponse()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer21.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I saw another post on SO suggesting that maybe it was windows updates related, so I went as far as installing fresh Windows Server 2012 R2 on a new VM and trying to run the site before doing any Windows Updates but to no avail. I also slowly applied updates and retried until all updates were done and still I ran into the issue.

From the error message, you can see I'm using a SOAP web service which has its own defined types in each service. Each service also has the type `TLocalizedValue[]` and from the error it looks like its getting mixed up between that of the `ProductService` and the `CustomerService`. In an attempt to fix that, I went and explicitly typed all of the `TLocalizedValue[]` fields in the services to their respective `ServiceRefName.TLocalizedValue[]` but that was useless also.

I'm left to believe that there is something funky going on with the `System.XML` library on Windows Server but I'm at a loss as to what. I don't think I understand it quite enough to drill into the problem and fix it.

Any guidance is much appreciated, Sean.

EDIT:

Not sure if it helps but here is the declaration of `TLocalizedValue` in the `ProductService` reference:

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1064.2")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn://epages.de/WebService/EpagesTypes/2005/01")]
    public partial class TLocalizedValue {

        private string languageCodeField;

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string LanguageCode {
            get {
                return this.languageCodeField;
            }
            set {
                this.languageCodeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Value {
            get {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

After some further testing, it turns out that the `CustomerService` DOES work, but none of the others do. They all seem to confuse their `TLocalizedValue` declaration as belonging to the `CustomerServiceRef`, as like the error above.

Comment: You have an array issue.  The default serialization for arrays expect two levels of an array like <Names><Name>.......</Name></Names>.  Adding an [XmlElement("Name")] declaration eliminates the <Names> tag.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure I follow, where are you seeing the array issue?

Comment: In the exception : Cannot assign object of type EpagesSOAPClients.CustomerService4Ref.TLocalizedValue[].  Can't give an answer without seeing the xml and more of your code.

Comment: Fair enough, I'd happily post more code but I think I'd overfill the post. I'll see if I can get the XML and look through it

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of this SO post, I've found my answer: [Switching to Release Build causes runtime error in Web Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468964/switching-to-release-build-causes-runtime-error-in-web-reference)

Somehow somewhere, my "Generate Serialization Assembly" option in all configs but "Debug" were set to "Auto". Setting to "Off" has fixed. I can't believe it took me this long to find one little dropdown list in the build config...

[image]