# Crashes in Win/Maci release build, works in Linux debug/release build and Maci/Win debug build

Tags: c++, debugging

My program crashes in Win/Maci release build, but works in Linux debug/release build and Maci/Win debug build. This is a large program, and I have not simplified it to a code that I can present here yet.

I have read related discussions here. For example,

[What are some reasons a Release build would run differently than a Debug build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312312/what-are-some-reasons-a-release-build-would-run-differently-than-a-debug-build)

[Program only crashes as release build -- how to debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186237/program-only-crashes-as-release-build-how-to-debug)

Given that my code works in linux in both release/debug build, while fails only in Win/Maci release build, does this reduce the possibilities that I should look into?

Many thanks.

Comment: windows and (i think mac) zero out stack memory when it's allocated. I expect you've failed to initialise a variable. in windows it's zero. in linux it's random.

Comment: If it is random in linux, I should have sporadic crashes in linux, but this seems not my case.

Comment: i think you're going to have to do what you probably have not done - write unit tests and run them in a release build

Comment: Does win/mac not zero out stack memory in its debug build?

Comment: windows zeros out all newly allocated memory pages when they are created (e.g. your stack and heap). linux does not. I cannot speak for OSX with certainty but we have seen bugs manifest themselves in linux that did not appear in osx. whether your program is debug or release is irrelevant

Comment: If so, this does not match my case: win/maci release build crashes, which their debug builds work.

Comment: you're overrunning a buffer somewhere, or inadvertently relying on a side effect that's optimised out of a release build. You need to write unit tests to prove that your interfaces are not lying.

Comment: OOB is exactly the problem. I have some code with important side effects in side a macro that will only run in debug build because that macro is defined to be nothing in release build. This eventually made out-of-bound access.