# What's the corresponding library in Linux as /MTd in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, runtime

Here's the question:
I wrote a piece of code on Windows. When using `/MT` option, the answer is wrong. When simply switching to `/MTd`, the answer is correct.
Now I'm <s>transplanting</s> porting this code to Linux. The answer is wrong using the following command: `g++ -Ofast -o test test.cpp`. Also, I'm quite sure that this is the only problem left.
I've installed `libc6`, `libc6-dbg`, `libc6-dev`, `libstdc++-4.8-dev`, `libstdc++6` and `libstdc++6-4.8-dbg`.
What's the problem in this situation and how can I solve it?

Update: Problem solved. Codes can run on Windows (Debug and Release mode) and Linux correctly with various optimization options. There were variable initialization problems. Thanks everyone.

Comment: this is the first time i'm seeing `porting` called `transplanting`. nice job on surprising me :)

Comment: If you want to build a debug version of your program, you add the `-g` flag when building using `gcc` or `g++`. That's all.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, this is not the essence of the question, however.

Comment: @SergeyA And that's why I didn't write an answer. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tried `-g` flag but it's not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312312/what-are-some-reasons-a-release-build-would-run-differently-than-a-debug-build

Comment: That's because the problem you are having is something in your code, not something to do with flags. Having debug information (generated when you use the `-g` flag) will help you debug your application, either by using a debugger and stepping through the code, or by using a tool such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) which will find memory overwrites in your program. Other than saying that, there's nothing more we can do without any code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. Great suggestions. I'll look into my codes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your code. The program behaving differently with debug and release version of C++ runtime library (this is what is controlled by /MT and /MTd)  means you have a bug in **your** program. Most likely undefined behavior.

The first thing would be change your compilation command to `g++ -O3 -Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o test test.cpp` and study compiler output. If you are lucky, you will see some warnings turned errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

1. Your g++ compile command is release mode. Use the `-g` option to compile with debug symbols.
2. You need to resolve on Windows why you don't get correct information in release mode with `/MT`.