# Recover call stack from a native c++ application on a user machine

Tags: windows, crash, native, callstack

The application I'm working on right now is crashing on one of the users machines at startup.  The user machine is running Windows XP and has lots of access restrictions, one of them is probably causing a problem.

How can I retrieve the call stack from the crash without installing any dev tools?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create minidump for my process when it crashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547211/how-to-create-minidump-for-my-process-when-it-crashes)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in XP, but in Vista/Win7:

1. Wait until the process is stuck at the "Would you like to submit this to Microsoft", *don't hit anything*
2. Open Task Manager => Processes tab => Right click your EXE
3. Select "Create Dump file"
4. Zip up the file, send to dev box

For XP there is a lightweight program called userdump.exe that you can use, but you said "no tools" :)

Comment: part of the problem is that I can not even open the task manager on that machine. I will probably use SetUnhandledExceptionFilter to handle crashes and StackWalk64 to get the call stack.