# Generating Mini Text Dump LInux

Tags: c++, linux, dump, crash-dumps, minidump

Following question describe for windows 
[How to create minidump for my process when it crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547211/how-to-create-minidump-for-my-process-when-it-crashes)

But how can I create mini crash  text dump on linux ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a signal handler.

Here is a slide deck on how to do it:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/3726406/Crash-N-Burn-Writing-Linux-application-fault-handlers

Here is the code form the slide deck:

https://github.com/gby/libcrash

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can get the exact same thing as a .NET MiniDump - but you will be able to produce a core dump on Linux that should get the information you are after. Make sure that core files are enabled by issuing a command such as:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

This will also set the maximum size of core dumps to be `unlimited` - you can tailor this as you wish to achieve the 'mini' aspect of your question. `man ulimit` is your friend here.

Then, run your process and while you it is running kill it. The signal I usually send is `SIG_ABRT` (Signal 6) as so:

```
kill -6 <pid>
```

If you don't know what the pid is, or how to get a pid, you probably need to read up some more on Linux.

Comment: Make sure your code is compiled with the `-g` flag (debug symbols) so you can make sense of the core dump. You can also use the signal's name (without the `SIG` prefix) to `kill` so you don't have to memorize the numbers: `kill -ABRT <pid>`

Comment: Thanks for the additions, Mike!

Comment: I am already generating core dump but I want to generate a small readable text dump