# Are minidump files useful for analysing .NET WinForms app crashes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, debugging, minidump

Are minidump files useful for analysing .NET WinForms app crashes? I notice that [NBug](https://nbug.codeplex.com/) has the option of producting them, but if I was to receive one, I'm not sure how it could help over looking at the stack trace.

How would one use this file for .NET debugging?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547211/how-to-create-minidump-for-my-process-when-it-crashes). The answer to that question might be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

A mini dump is a very broad category of dumps. You can create a mini dump with full process memory, and you can create a mini dump that doesn't contain anything except loaded modules and some stack pages. To debug managed dumps, you need the regions of memory that contain JIT-ted code to be available to the debugger in the dump file. The easiest way to do this is to create a full dump (mini dump with full memory). You can then inspect it using the SOS extension in WinDbg, or you can simply drag-and-drop it into Visual Studio 2010 or higher.