# C++ debug release version

Tags: c++, debugging

Very basic question. 
I want to debug release version of my exe. My debug version is working fine. But release version crashing as usual.

Any tool or debugger available for this would be a great help.

Comment: Which flavor of C++ are you using? GC, VC or anything else?

Comment: You need to mention what OS, architecture, compiler, etc that you are using.

Comment: @Paul R: exe probably means MSVC.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: you may be right, but sometimes people say "exe" as a short-hand for an "executable" on any platform, and anyway we really shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: I've often found that release-only bugs (ugh, I hate "debug mode" vs "release mode" .. compilers have no such thing!) can be traced to timing bugs. Your code is running more slowly with optimisations disabled, giving something time to complete or giving something time to change, that isn't the case when your fast, optimised executable runs. A perfect example is if you're erroneously `srand()`-ing on every tick, and your debug `std::cout` is slowing everything down such that it _looks_ like you're getting a proper random sequence. With optimisations you just see the same number over and over.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Program only crashes as release build -- how to debug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186237/program-only-crashes-as-release-build-how-to-debug)

Comment: @All: There is no information in the OP's post to infer anything, There is no effort even to give details of the problem/crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still enable debug information in release mode, and use a debugger as usual. Nothing particular here, except that the order of instructions will sometimes look weird when debugging due to optimizations.

Good luck, debugging release-mode-only bugs is tedious.

Comment: also in release mode the debugger is likely to step over, or not willing to step into, lots of source since it was optimized so hard that the resulting assembly doesn't seem to have much in common with the source anymore

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you adding some kind of logging system or trace points to locate the source of crash. The debugger can trick you when debugging release. You can also elevate the warning level of your compiler to see some usual suspects such as use of unitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to run exe under some memory debugger, such as Rational Purify or BoundsChecker. It will spot memory related bugs in your code, if any.